# Date Picker within an AntD filter

Tags: reactjs, antd

Is it possible to make a filter on a AntD table column that looks something like this?

[image]

The end goal is to be able to pick a date range and filter the column based on that. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RangePicker](https://ant.design/components/date-picker#components-date-picker-demo-range-picker). Something like this:

```
<RangePicker
  onChange={yourOnChangeFunction}
 />
```

Where the yourOnChangeFunction should filter your data and store the filtered data on the state.